What is the name of a totally ordered set that cannot be ordered in a strictly increasing sequence?
Let $X$ be a countable set with $\leq$ a total order on $X$ and $<$ the corresponding strict total order on $X$.  Suppose $X$ has the property that we cannot order the elements in $X$ into a strictly increasing sequence
$$
x_1 <x_2 <x_3<\cdots
$$
where $x_1$ is a unique minimal value in $X$.  The totally ordered set $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is an example of such a set.  What would we call such sets?

We would call them sets that are not order isomorphic to the natural numbers.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. @LeeMosher

It is not the set that creates this issue but the order.  You can order $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ for example with $\frac{0}{1} \prec \frac{1}{1} \prec \frac{1}{2} \prec \frac{1}{3} \prec \frac{2}{3}  \prec \frac{1}{4} \prec \frac{3}{4} \prec \frac{1}{5}  \prec \frac{2}{5} \prec \cdots$.

@MartinBrandenburg: Yes. But sometimes it is rather unclear to me whether I am addressing what the OP actually wants to know (as opposed to what they are literally asking), and then I may wait before making my answer into an answer.

I see. Thanks for explaining!

A set where every subset has a minimal element is said to be well-ordered, so your sets are not well-ordered.  This includes many orders that are not isomorphic to the naturals, it is all the ordinals and if your set is countable it is all the countable ordinals.  So, for example, the order $1 \prec 3 \prec 5 \prec 7 \ldots \prec 2 \prec 4 \prec 6 \ldots$ matches the ordinal $\omega + \omega$  It has all the naturals in a strictly increasing sequence.

A totally ordered set for which you can write the elements as $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < \cdots$ can be called a set which is order isomorphic to the natural numbers.
So, a set which cannot be written in that manner can be called a set which is not order isomorphic to the natural numbers. I have not heard of any "positive" name for such an ordered set, meaning a name which is something other than a negation of something else. And it would not make much sense to have a positive name for this concept, given that it comprises such a vast variety of totally ordered sets.
